# Android image view with scroll bar

Tags: android

How to make an image on android view with match_parent width and auto height ratio?
The view must have a vertical scroll bar that will allow us to see the reset of the image. Below the image some buttons.

The drawing below can give an idea of what I am trying to achieve.

```
-------------- 
|            ||
| image      || 
|            ||
|-------------
|    Buttons  |
---------------
```

Comment: wrap your imageView using a scrollView (vertical)

Answer (score 1):

You can use view pager .

```
 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp" />

        int[] images={R.drawable.pr1,R.drawable.pr2,R.drawable.pr3,R.drawable.pr4,R.drawable.pr5};
viewPager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    adapter=new CircleViewAdapter(StartScreen.this,images);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Adapter:

```
public class CircleViewAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
private Context mContext;
LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
private int[] mResources;

public CircleViewAdapter(Context context, int[] resources) {
    mContext = context;
    mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mResources = resources;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

    View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.flipper_item,container,false);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flipimage);
    imageView.setImageResource(mResources[position]);

    container.addView(itemView);
    return itemView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {
    collection.removeView((View) view);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mResources.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}
```

}

Comment: What I want is just the layout design. Is it possible to do the design without using java code?